# SMTPAuthenticationError on apache but not in the standard server. DJANGO and Apache2

Tags: django, apache, email, ssl, gmail

When I am doing python manage.py runsever 0.0.0.0:8000
Everything is working correctly. I am just using django server by MY_ADRESS_IP:8000

When I am using apache2 on the Centos 7 I have an error when I want to send an email.

My settings:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'MY_EMAIL_NAME'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'MY_EMAIL_PASS'
```

Do I need some special config in apache to let the gmail send emails?

Here more error details:

```
Django Version: 3.1.3
Python Version: 3.6.8
Installed Applications:
['sf_platform.apps.SfSplatformConfig',
 'sf_users.apps.SfUsersConfig',
 'sf_api.apps.SfApiConfig',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user_name/WEB-Platform/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/user_name/WEB-Platform/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/user_name/WEB-Platform/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user_name/WEB-Platform/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user_name/WEB-Platform/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user_name/WEB-Platform/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 222, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user_name/WEB-Platform/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user_name/WEB-Platform/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 142, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "/home/user_name/WEB-Platform/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 235, in form_valid
    form.save(**opts)
  File "/home/user_name/WEB-Platform/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 325, in save
    user_email, html_email_template_name=html_email_template_name,
  File "/home/user_name/WEB-Platform/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 273, in send_mail
    email_message.send()
  File "/home/user_name/WEB-Platform/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 284, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/home/user_name/WEB-Platform/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 102, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/home/user_name/WEB-Platform/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 69, in open
    self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 730, in login
    raise last_exception
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 721, in login
    initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 642, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)

Exception Type: SMTPAuthenticationError at /accounts/password_reset
Exception Value: (535, b'Incorrect authentication daata')
```

Comment: did you enabled ```less secure apps``` in your gmail account?

Comment: yup, I tried this.

Answer (score 0):

Oh....

I just found in my WHM panel something like "SMTP Restrictions" enabled.

I just disabled it and it's working :D
So that was just apache config problem